# Automatic color sequence in subplots - Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am automatically generating numerous figures where each figure has 7 subplots.
in each subplot there are numerous traces (up to 17 in one subplot).

In which sequence does Matplotlib assign the colors of the traces automatically as I need to generate a figure key.

i.e. if I have in my code for a subplot with four traces:

```
axarr[0, 0].plot(data for trace 1) #what would matlibplot color assignment be

axarr[0, 0].plot(data for trace 2) #what would matlibplot color assignment be

axarr[0, 0].plot(data for trace 3) #what would matlibplot color assignment be

axarr[0, 0].plot(data for trace 4) #what would matlibplot color assignment be
```

Comment: Which version of matplotlib are you using?

Comment: In any case, the answer is here - https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html#colors-color-cycles-and-color-maps

Answer (score 0):

There are only 8 predefined colors according to the [Matlb `colorspec` documentation](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorspec.html).

But you can easily generate a matrix with colors yourself and pick them by index to make sure you get consistent colors.

```
>> C=ones(17, 3) ./ [1:17]'

C =

    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000
    0.3333    0.3333    0.3333
    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500
    0.2000    0.2000    0.2000
    0.1667    0.1667    0.1667
    0.1429    0.1429    0.1429
    0.1250    0.1250    0.1250
    0.1111    0.1111    0.1111
    0.1000    0.1000    0.1000
    0.0909    0.0909    0.0909
    0.0833    0.0833    0.0833
    0.0769    0.0769    0.0769
    0.0714    0.0714    0.0714
    0.0667    0.0667    0.0667
    0.0625    0.0625    0.0625
    0.0588    0.0588    0.0588

>> C(1, :)

ans =

     1     1     1

>> C(17, :)

ans =

    0.0588    0.0588    0.0588
```

You could then add `'Color', C[index, :]` to you plot command, see the [`LineSpec`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#btzitot-LineSpec) parameter of plot

Comment: OP is using python, not MATLAB

Comment: Oops, missed that. The solution offered still stands though as according to the matplotlib documentation you can also supply a 1x3 vector with numeric values to define color as can be seen on https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/api/colors_api.html